# BackupPC not completing backups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, backuppc

I'm running `BackupPC` on `Ubuntu server` and it suddenly stopped working. I'm getting the following error:

```
File /var/lib/backuppc/pc/mail.vpl.lan/LOG.122015
Contents of file /var/lib/backuppc/pc/mail.vpl.lan/LOG.122015, modified 2015-12-18 23:07:54

2015-12-02 20:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-11-26 20:00:00 (backup #292) for directory /
2015-12-02 20:09:54 incr backup 294 complete, 1480 files, 839929564 bytes, 0 xferErrs (0 bad files, 0 bad shares, 0 other)
2015-12-02 20:09:54 removing incr backup 284
2015-12-05 20:00:00 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #294)
2015-12-05 20:57:21 full backup 295 complete, 129178 files, 27143356140 bytes, 0 xferErrs (0 bad files, 0 bad shares, 0 other)
2015-12-05 20:57:21 removing incr backup 285
2015-12-05 20:57:22 removing full backup 283
2015-12-08 05:18:32 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-08 20:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-08 21:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-08 22:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-08 23:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 01:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 02:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 03:00:00 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 04:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 05:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 06:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 20:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 21:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 22:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-09 23:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 01:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 02:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 03:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 04:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 05:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 06:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 20:00:00 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 21:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 22:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-10 23:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 01:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 02:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 03:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 04:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 05:00:08 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 06:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 20:00:00 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 21:00:03 removing incr backup 287
2015-12-11 21:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 22:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-11 23:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 01:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 02:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 03:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 04:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 05:00:13 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 06:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 07:00:06 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 08:00:06 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 09:00:01 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 10:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 11:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 12:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 13:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 14:00:00 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 15:00:00 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 16:00:05 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 17:00:02 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 18:00:03 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 19:00:04 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-12 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-12 21:00:04 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-12 22:22:37 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-12 23:33:29 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 01:00:14 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 03:13:43 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 04:40:57 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 05:54:56 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 06:58:14 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 08:03:16 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 09:27:57 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 10:38:53 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 12:00:37 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 13:16:10 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 14:33:39 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 15:53:43 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 16:55:33 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 18:04:41 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 19:03:56 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 20:20:53 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 21:26:00 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 22:21:36 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-13 23:55:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 01:00:09 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 03:27:11 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 04:28:04 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 05:38:58 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 06:45:36 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 20:00:01 removing incr backup 288
2015-12-14 20:00:01 removing full backup 286
2015-12-14 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 21:14:22 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 22:12:13 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-14 23:33:13 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 01:00:07 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 03:09:46 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 04:21:30 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 05:48:48 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 06:52:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 21:34:07 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 22:29:44 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-15 23:54:20 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 01:00:16 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 03:48:49 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 04:44:36 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 06:13:05 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 21:04:42 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 22:02:43 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-16 23:20:14 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 01:00:04 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 02:59:17 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 04:08:41 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 05:11:37 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 06:16:19 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 21:03:57 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 22:03:39 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-17 23:21:11 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 01:00:07 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 03:10:18 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 04:18:02 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 05:22:43 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 06:22:33 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 20:00:01 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 21:03:59 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 22:03:21 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
2015-12-18 22:57:53 incr backup started back to 2015-12-05 20:00:00 (backup #295) for directory /
2015-12-18 23:07:54 full backup started for directory / (baseline backup #295)
```

Backup starts normally and looks like it's working. The problem is that it never finishes and backups are not visible under `Browse backups` dropdown.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the only thing that `/var/lib/backuppc` shows?